# Switching on function with multiple parameters

Tags: php, polymorphism, switch-statement

When i've got a `Car` instance which extends a `VehicleType`

```
abstract class VehicleType {

}

class Car extends VehicleType {

}


/**
 * @var VehicleType $vehicleType
 */
private $vehicleType;
```

And the `$vehicleType` variable can be any instance of `VehicleType` and i want to make a switch function on that like this:

```
$vehicleType = new Car();

switch (is_a($vehicleType, get_class($vehicleType))) {
   ...
}
```

On what parameter does the switch function listen to? Can i do something like this now:

```
switch (is_a($vehicleType, get_class($vehicleType))) {
    case "Car": {
       //Its now a Car
    }
    case "Motorcyle": {
       //Its now a motorcycle
    }
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
switch (get_class($vehicleType))) { //it will get class name of $vehicleType
    case "Car": {   //match if $vehicleType is Car
       //Its now a Car
        break;
    }
    case "Motorcyle": {   //match if $vehicleType is Motorcyle
       //Its now a motorcycle
        break;
    }
    //etc
}
```

Comment: But i'm using it in a function and wanting to check if `$vehicleType`is an instance of an item in the switch.

Comment: @Bas Do you want to match class type of `$vehicleType` with set of Class names (Car, Motorcycle)? Or you just want to check if *class type is in a list of types??* Whats your need, if you want to perform specific action for each class-type you can go with solution I provided with `switch`.

Comment: Well, that's not really nessacery i guess. I just wanted to do an different action on every different VehicleType, i thought that would be done with the `is_a` function (already succeeded with an `if` statement)

Comment: @Bas Check my update then! It can be done without using is_a function and avoid a extra function call.

Comment: @How does it come i cant switch on the `is_a` method though?

Comment: @Bas Because, is_a() will return only `boolean` based on comparison. So it cant switch it around multiple cases provided. Boolean responce can be either true/false. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: So you mean i would only be able to switch on true and false?

Answer (score 1):

is_a returns boolean so you need to do a if-else checking.

Like this:

```
if (is_a($vehicleType, "Car")) {
    //It's now a Car
} else if (is_a($vehicleType, "Motorcyle")) {
    //It's now a motorcycle
} else {
    //It's something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use an switch statement :)